# screen orientation to portrait only

Tags: android

I'm building a phonegap app and i want to set the screen orientation to portrait only. i've done all that i should be after compling and testing on a samsung s4 device, it still rotates when i rotate my screen

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
        android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 

        <intent-filter></intent-filter>
         </activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the orientation parameter to your MainActivity?

Comment: how do i do that? i'm new this this whole thing

Comment: @petey appears to have done that for you in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first activity in manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" //Here
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
    android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 

    <intent-filter></intent-filter>
     </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following attribute to your MainActivity's activity tag:
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: this should be pasted in the MainActivity.java?

Comment: just add the missing attribute and value, see the edit.